# Enter pressed is not being read by AbstractAction

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have this line of code that works with all of the keys like F1 and ESCAPE.
Im having a problem with the Enter Key.

Do I need to do a focus on components?
I am not sure why only ENTER is not working.

Does it need special treatment compared to the other keys?

```
InputMap inputMap = rootPane
                .getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
KeyStroke enterstroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER");



        inputMap.put(enterstroke, "ENTER");
rootPane.getActionMap().put("ENTER", enterPresedActionListener);


Action entersActionListener = new AbstractAction() {
.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a KeyListener to my JTextField and somehow it made it work

Comment: Post your [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. You should NOT be adding a KeyListener to the text field. Note, for a JTextField you can add an ActionListener to the text field to be invoked when focus is on the text field and the Enter key is pressed.